# Use Gson to serialize complex set

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I have a method, `setFriends()`, that takes a Set. This method is in another module and I want to send `setFriends()` serialized data via Gson().fromJson(). I am not sure if I have the `arg` string correct. I have tried the following which failed:

```
// my attempt to serialize
String arg = "[Friend[name=Dave, relationship=Relationship[Work]], Friend[name=Jack, relationship=Relationship[School]]]"; // not sure if this string is correct
Type type = new TypeToken<Set<Friend>>(){}.getType();
Set<Friend> payload = new Gson().fromJson(arg, type);
sendPayload(payload); // will send payload to People.setFriends()



// code from the other module:

Set<Friend>

public class People {
    public void setFriends(Set<Friend> friends) { ... }
}

public class Friend {
    String name;
    Relationship relationship;
}

public enum Relationship {
    School,
    Work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Gson is a simple Java-based library to serialize Java objects to JSON and vice versa.
 In JSON we represent objects using `{}`. For nested objects we use `"fieldName": {<nested object>}`.

In your example I've considered `relationship` as an enum. And introduced `Address` as a nested object. JSON for the `Friend` object will look like this:

```
{ 
  "name" : "Dave",
  "relationship" : "WORK",
  "address" : {"street" : "s1"}
}
```

There is no representation for Set structure in JSON so you put elements in list.
Following is the sample java code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String arg = "["
                + "{\"name\":\"Dave\",\"relationship\":\"WORK\",\"address\":{\"street\":\"s1\"}},"
                + "{\"name\":\"Jack\",\"relationship\":\"SCHOOL\",\"address\":{\"street\":\"s2\"}},"
                + "{\"name\":\"Dave\",\"relationship\":\"GYM\",\"address\":{\"street\":\"s3\"}}"
                + "]";
        Type type = new TypeToken<Set<Friend>>(){}.getType();
        Set<Friend> payload = new Gson().fromJson(arg, type);
        sendPayload(payload);
    }
    static void sendPayload(Set<Friend> plod) {
        System.out.println("Sent payload: " + plod.toString());
    }
}

class Friend {
    private String name;
    private Relationship relationship;
    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Relationship getRelationship() {
        return relationship;
    }

    public void setRelationship(Relationship relationship) {
        this.relationship = relationship;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return name.equals(obj.toString());
    }
    
}

enum Relationship {
    WORK, SCHOOL, GYM
}

class Address {
    String street;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sent payload: [Dave, Jack]
```

In my environment Gson returned `LinkedHashSet` object. If you want different set like sorted ones. Then you can deserialize the Json into `List<Freind>` then convert it to the desired set.